# Update VueJS project to Node16

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, node-sass

I have to update my Node JS from 14.17.3 to 16.14.2 and if I run the project (made with node 14) with node 16 this is what happens:

```
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)
For more information on which environments are supported please see: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1
```

I've tried to update node-sass (with node 14) using `npm update`, `npm install node-sass@6.0.1` or `npm uninstall node-sass` => `npm install sass` but this get always the same error or sometimes:

```
SassError: (mobile: 320px, ipad: 768px, desktop: 1368px) isn't a valid CSS value.
```

This is the list of pakage used for my project (`npm outdated` on node 14):

```
Package                      Current  Wanted  Latest  Location

@stripe/stripe-js             1.15.0  1.27.0  1.27.0  myproject
@vue/cli-plugin-babel         4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/cli-plugin-eslint        4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/cli-plugin-pwa           4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/cli-plugin-router        4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/cli-plugin-vuex          4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/cli-service              4.5.12  4.5.17   5.0.4  myproject
@vue/eslint-config-standard    5.1.2   5.1.2   6.1.0  myproject
axios                         0.21.1  0.21.4  0.26.1  myproject
core-js                       3.13.1  3.21.1  3.21.1  myproject
dinero.js                      1.8.1   1.9.1   1.9.1  myproject
eslint                         6.8.0   6.8.0  8.13.0  myproject
eslint-plugin-import          2.22.1  2.26.0  2.26.0  myproject
eslint-plugin-promise          4.3.1   4.3.1   6.0.0  myproject
eslint-plugin-standard         4.1.0   4.1.0   5.0.0  myproject
eslint-plugin-vue              6.2.2   6.2.2   8.6.0  myproject
gsap                           3.6.1  3.10.3  3.10.3  myproject
moment                        2.29.1  2.29.2  2.29.2  myproject
node-sass                     4.14.1  4.14.1   7.0.1  myproject
qs                            6.10.1  6.10.3  6.10.3  myproject
sass-loader                    8.0.2   8.0.2  12.6.0  myproject
sass-mq                        5.0.1   5.0.1   6.0.0  myproject
vue                           2.6.12  2.6.14  3.2.32  myproject
vue-inner-image-zoom           1.0.1   1.1.1   2.0.0  myproject
vue-router                     3.5.1   3.5.3  4.0.14  myproject
vue-template-compiler         2.6.12  2.6.14  2.6.14  myproject
vuex                           3.6.2   3.6.2   4.0.2  myproject
```

Based on what I've read around Node 16 require node-sass 6.0.0 or higher but even if I try `install node-sass@6.0.1` I get the same error. How I can do?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

1. Use node 14. Select using nvm.
2. Use:
   "node-sass": "~6.0"
   "sass-loader": "^10.2.0"
3. Uninstall node-sass. Install sass (dart-sass). Add to vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
      },
    },
  }
}
```

4. Use vue-cli v5

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to comment but can't do so yet.
You can try doing `npm ls node-sass` to check your dependency tree for something that is forcing it to install a version below 6.

Comment: There are no other dependency, this is what i get: └── node-sass@4.14.1 and nothing else

Comment: You mentioned you installed node-sass@6.0.1. Make sure you did that (node-sass v6.x) if you're using node v16. https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy

Comment: You can try deleting node_modules folder, change node-sass version to 6.0.1 in package.json and try `npm install`